# Prove that among any five distinct real numbers there are two, $a$ and $b$, such that $|ab+1|\gt|a-b|$. Solution without trigonometry?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, inequality, substitution, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that among any five distinct real numbers there are two, $a$ and $b$, such that $\lvert ab+1\lvert 
>  \ \gt \ \vert a-b \vert$.

**Solution:** I have solved the above problem using Trigonometrical substitution by writing $-90^\circ <\tan\ x_k<90^\circ$, $k=1,2,3,4,5$,  and considering the intervals $(-90^\circ,-45^\circ)$; $(-45^\circ,0^\circ)$; $(0^\circ,45^\circ)$; $(45^\circ,90^\circ)$. Then by Pigeonhole Principle , at least two of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ will lie in the same interval. Let those two be $(x_i,x_j)$ as $\vert x_i-x_j\vert\lt 45^\circ$ setting $a=\tan x_i$ and $b=\tan x_j$ we get the desired inequality. $\square$

> However, I was wondering whether we could approach this problem in an algebraic way because this question is in an Algebraic Book which I have.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that any approach taken will require using the pigeonhole principle, which is exactly what you did.  It also seems that although your approach is based on trigonometry, you then explored the algebraic relationship between the two points in the same region.  Therefore my **blind instinct** is that an alternative solution will not have analysis significantly different than yours.

Comment: This question has already been asked so many times, but all have been answered using trigonometric substitution. For example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531468/for-any-given-set-of-13-distinct-real-numbers-prove-we-can-always-find-two-numb) , [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573849/show-that-given-seven-real-numbers-it-is-always-possible-take-two-of-them-such) , [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250549/for-any-7-different-real-numbers-there-are-among-them-two-numbers-x-and-y-such).....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the same argument can be made algebraically: at least one of the intervals $(\leftarrow,-1)$, $[-1,0)$, $[0,1)$, and $[1,\to)$ must contain two of the numbers, say $a$ and $b$. We may assume that $a<b$ and let $d=b-a$. (Note that your four intervals are not quite exhaustive, since all of them are open.) Taking the intervals in reverse order:

- if $1\le a<b$, then $$|ab+1|=a^2+ad+1\ge d+2>d=|a-b|\,;$$
- if $0\le a<b<1$, then $$|ab+1|=a^2+ad+1\ge 1>d=|a-b|\,;$$
- if $-1\le a<b<0$, then $$|ab+1|=ab+1>1>d=|a-b|\,;\text{ and}$$
- if $a<b<-1$, then $$|ab+1|=b^2-bd+1>2-bd=2+|b|d>d=|a-b|\,.$$

Comment: Is it possible to find "magical algebraic way" that, doesn't use separate intervals? Is it possible?

Comment: @lonestudent: I don’t know. I strongly suspect that any solution that does not use the pigeonhole principle in more or less this fashion will be more complicated.

Comment: (+)Thank you so much.  I noticed on this site that you are returning to all comments asked to you.  You care about everyone.  This is a very beautiful thing.  I wish you health and well-being.!

Comment: @lonestudent: I sometimes miss a comment or forget to answer one, but I do try. The same to you!

Answer (score 2):

Your use of the tangent function is a good inspiration from your knowledge of trigonometry, but you can avoid it just by making the intervals be for the $x_k$ instead of their tangents and making the intervals $(-\infty,-1], (-1,0],(0,1],(1,\infty)$.  Now show that if two of the points are in the same interval the desired inequality is satisfied.  For example, if $a,b \in (0,1]$ we have
$$|ab+1|=ab+1\gt 1 \gt |a-b|$$

You can prove it for the other three intervals as well.  Someone who does not know any trig might think you had a miraculous inspiration to choose these intervals, but $0$ and $\pm 1$ are often special when multiplication is involved.

Comment: This answer really made me understand that we are just partitioning the real numbers so that we can apply PHP on them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to speak of $5$ distinct real numbers, since you're not using the remaining three
But instead I suggest, $2$ distinct number
$$\lvert ab+1\lvert 
 \ \gt \ \vert a-b \vert$$
$$ (ab+1)^2 \gt (a-b)^2 $$
$$ a^2b^2+2ab+1 \gt a^2-2ab+b^2$$
$$ a^2b^2+2ab+1+4ab \gt a^2-2ab+b^2+4ab$$
$$a^2b^2+6ab+1 \gt a^2+2ab+b^2$$
$$a^2b^2+6ab+1 \gt ( a+b)^2 $$
$$ab( ab+6)+1 \gt (a+b)^2 $$
It's easy to know that $ ab \gt a+b$, for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$ab \cdot (ab+6) +1 \gt (a+b) \cdot (a+b) $$
Then the identity is true, or are you trying to proof it with trigonometry alone

Comment: $ab>a+b$ ? No, It is easy to know that the statement is false.(not always hold)

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, what do you say

Comment: I can say $a>1, b<\frac{a}{a-1}$

Comment: Why $a,b \in\mathbb Z$, question says $a,b$ are real.

Comment: That was a typo error,

Comment: My assumption that $ab \gt a+b $ is for $\mathbb{Z}$